# Not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable when reading Sequence File with Spark / Scala

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, serialization, sequencefile

Reading a sequence file with Int and String logically,

then if I do this:

```
val sequence_data = sc.sequenceFile("/seq_01/seq-directory/*", classOf[IntWritable], classOf[Text])
                  .map{case (x, y) => (x.toString(), y.toString().split("/")(0), y.toString().split("/")(1))}
                  .collect
```

this is ok as the IntWritable is converted to String.

If I do this:

```
val sequence_data = sc.sequenceFile("/seq_01/seq-directory/*", classOf[IntWritable], classOf[Text])
                  .map{case (x, y) => (x, y.toString().split("/")(0), y.toString().split("/")(1))}
                  .collect
```

then I get this error immediately:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5.0 in stage 42.0 (TID 692) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
```

Underlying reason is not really clear - serialization, but why so difficult? This is another type of serialization aspect I note. Also it is only noted at run-time.

Comment: Well, Strings are subclasses from Serializable, IntWritable is not. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html

Comment: So reading a sequence file means all aspects should be set to String and then processed and converted from there onwards?

Comment: No, you can `x.get()`, then Integers are serializable as well (and less overhead of serializing strings)

Comment: I took the get() out in this example. Ok, gotcha!

Comment: You may as well make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to just get an Integer value, you would need to call a get on the writable

```
.map{case (x, y) => (x.get()
```

And then the JVM handles [serialization of the Integer object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) rather than not knowing how to process a IntWritable because [it doesn't implement the Serializable interface](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/IntWritable.html)

[String does implement Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)